# Is it correct to say "Have you been to abroad?"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to say

> Have you been **to** abroad?

or there is only one way to say it as  following

> Have you been abroad?

Comment: I've only ever heard of the latter example, that is, without “to”, and with additional context. Otherwise “Have you **ever** been abroad?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Have you been to ...* is for particular places.  For example, you could say *Have you been to Europe?* or *Have you been to Australia*?  Abroad is not a particular place.  It means *away from home*<sup>1</sup>.  You must say *Have you been abroad?* which means *Have you been out of your country?*

<sub><sup>1</sup>source: [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abroad)</sub>